# Exchange 2016 on Windows Server 2012 BSoD

Tags: exchange, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2016

I have an Exchange 2016 Server which bsods with about 14 days inbetween.
The server is virtual and exists in a clustered vmware environment with storage via iSCSI. None of the other Windows servers we have running (including the passive copy of Exchange) bsods. The passive Exchange is beeing backed up and clears the transaction-logs as it should on both the passive and active node.

- I have tried installing the latest critical patches (none of the optional yet)
- I have tried migrating the VM in question to a new host.

Here is what BSoD viewer gives me of information:

```
052716-21921-01.dmp 27.05.2016 10:22:16 CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED   0x000000ef  ffffe000`de10d080   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+14e3a0 NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.3.9600.18289 (winblue_ltsb.160328-1315)   x64 ntoskrnl.exe+14e3a0                 C:\Windows\Minidump\052716-21921-01.dmp 8   15  9600    138 150 27.05.2016 10:22:47 
051516-25765-01.dmp 15.05.2016 10:11:06 CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED   0x000000ef  ffffe001`0ad80900   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+14e3a0 NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.3.9600.18289 (winblue_ltsb.160328-1315)   x64 ntoskrnl.exe+14e3a0                 C:\Windows\Minidump\051516-25765-01.dmp 8   15  9600    138 150 15.05.2016 10:11:41 
042816-19328-01.dmp 28.04.2016 22:36:50 CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED   0x000000ef  ffffe001`3da4f900   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+14e8a0 NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.3.9600.18289 (winblue_ltsb.160328-1315)   x64 ntoskrnl.exe+14e8a0                 C:\Windows\Minidump\042816-19328-01.dmp 8   15  9600    294 472 28.04.2016 22:39:45 
041916-23859-01.dmp 19.04.2016 08:43:53 CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED   0x000000ef  ffffe001`23101900   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   00000000`00000000   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+14e8a0 NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.3.9600.18289 (winblue_ltsb.160328-1315)   x64 ntoskrnl.exe+14e8a0                 C:\Windows\Minidump\041916-23859-01.dmp 8   15  9600    294 472 19.04.2016 08:47:04
```

I saw a post with the same problem on a diffrent site, but none actually answered the problem and the post aged out.

Do anyone have any pointers on how to fix this? 
Would I have to install ANOTHTER Exchange server and migrate into? This would be very unfortunate..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your storage system is failing or too slow to keep up. If IO has been stalled for too long, Exchange thinks that storage is dead and kills Wininit to force hard reset.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625233.aspx and scroll to the end. It's the same for 2013 and 2016.

> In some cases, the entire storage stack may be affected by the hang, making it impossible to write failure events to the crimson channel or any other area of the Windows Event Log. ESE also monitors the crimson channel by verifying that the event log can be written to. If writing to the event log fails for a long period of time, MSExchangeRepl intentionally causes a bugcheck of Windows by terminating wininit.exe. When the operating system I/O is hung, the system is obviously unable to write any ESE events to the event log.

I have experienced it firsthand when using Windows Server Backup to backup Exchange. When backup begins, it will do consistency check on all databases in parallel. This caused Exchange to BSoD after a few minutes when storage dropped out.

First solution is to disable ATS heartbeat to storage array
https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2113956

Text is too long to copy but TL;DR: Your storage array connection may be dropped under heavy IO when ATS heartbeat of 8 seconds times out, that will cause IO timeout in VM, causing Exchange to BSoD.

Secondary solution is to add storage controllers to VM and distribute database disks between controllers. In my case, single pvscsi controller would choke badly under 6 databases, but when disks (including OS disk etc) were distributed over 4 pvscsi controllers, issues disappeared. I don't have a reference for that, just personal experience on vSphere 5.5 U3.

Comment: Disabling the ATS heartbeat sounds intrusive if there is a change that can be done on the Exchange server. The ATS part would change for all the servers on all the VM-hosts?  Adding storage-controllers could be a viable solution, but at the times the server BSODs there isn't alot of stuff happening on the storage side; but I don't doubt you're right (that its due to IO).

Comment: When I investigated the issue, I found out that ATS times out waaaaay too easily on many SANs and it had happened regardless of Exchange (no BSoD or kernel panic though) but didn't get to monitoring as the event is only logged by ESXi kernel and not reported to vCenter. But yes, you would change it for all the hosts. In my case these 2 actions were somewhat independent. Without ATS heartbeat change, VM would crash within 5 minutes (loss of SAN connection also causing issues for other VMs). After the change, IO would choke only on Exchange after maybe an hour.

Comment: Interesting! I tried the other answer making an override, but will definitly look into this too. Thanks for the great feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You can issue a command to disable the ESE forced reboot, the cause is well explained by Don's answer.

I did it lately for a customer with a single server with ESXi, as the IO was overkilling the Exchange. (its still killing it, as it take age to simply open a management console in example, but at least it doesn't reboot..)

```
Add-GlobalMonitoringOverride -Identity Exchange\ActiveDirectoryConnectivityConfigDCServerReboot -ItemType Responder -PropertyName Enabled -PropertyValue 0 -ApplyVersion '15.0.712.24'
```

In there you need to use the correct Exchange version.

See here for Exchange version; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh135098(v=exchg.150).aspx

See here for further detail; http://www.tecfused.com/2014/11/exchange-2013-dag-bsod/

Comment: I tried running the command provided but it tells me the "monitoring item identity" does not exist. The closest I can get is "ActiveDirectoryConnectivityConfigDCMonitor".

Comment: Ofcourse, I was missing a "\" between "Exchange" and "ActiveDirectoryConnectivityConfigDCServerReboot". Added that, and the command had no problems running.